# snap svg not working locally

Tags: css, animation, svg, snap.svg

I made a codepen with snap svg. Seen [HERE](http://codepen.io/Alex/pen/PwjVXq)

I want to include it into a site I am developing locally with Kirby CMS and MAMP

I have included snap svg like so in the head:

```
<?php echo js('assets/js/snap.svg-min.js') ?>
```

and befor the closing body tag after the footer I have this script:

```
<script>

      s = Snap("#svg");

      var firstShape = s.path("M125.834,113L125.834,113v-3.625H130l0,0V113H125.834z").attr({
        fill: "#07AD91"
      });


      var secondShape = s.path("M0,3.63L0,3.63V0.004h4.167l0,0V3.63H0z").attr({
        fill: "#07AD91"
      });



      firstShape.animate({ d: "M10.011,112.182L0,94.098l54.068-92.65l40.161,71.15H73.607L53.62,37.577L10.011,112.182z;" fill:"#46CEB4" }, 2500, mina.elastic);

      secondShape.animate({ d: "M130,91.641H49.094l11.094-16.658h38.5L56.472,0h20.471l42.236,72.818L130,91.641z" fill:"#97E8DA" }, 2500, mina.elastic);

    </script>
```

It works on codepen but locally I have this error in the console:

[image: console screenshot]

I've tried linking up snap svg throgh clodflare, putting it in the footer, wrapping in the code in a doc ready function. But nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

A comma is missing before `fill:"#46CEB4"`, the code should be:

```
firstShape.animate({ d: "M10.011,112.182L0,94.098l54.068-92.65l40.161,71.15H73.607L53.62,37.577L10.011,112.182z;", fill:"#46CEB4" }, 2500, mina.elastic);

secondShape.animate({ d: "M130,91.641H49.094l11.094-16.658h38.5L56.472,0h20.471l42.236,72.818L130,91.641z", fill:"#97E8DA" }, 2500, mina.elastic);
```

Comment: Thank you! I was fiddling around trying to fix this for over an hour